# What triggers a Game Over screen?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

The game tells you that if Noctis' max HP falls to zero, the game will end. However, I've had this happen once (damn Galvanades), and though the action stopped, the game did not end. I was then able to use a Phoenix Down on Noctis and resume fighting. This was on normal difficulty; I understand the game will save you on easy mode.

So what actually causes the game to end? Would this normally end the game, but it gave me a pass for some reason? Does your whole party have to wipe out for you to lose and the tip is wrong? Or is it something else?

Comment: I'm surprised this hasn't been asked before. The only times I ever get a game over is when I crash the Regalia

Comment: I don't _think_ even having everyone down will trigger game over automatically (easy enough to test this using the 'Elder Coeurl' hunt, or during any segment where Noct is the only party member).  The only time I've gotten a game over in combat was when I wandered off to get a drink after 'pausing' the game by opening the item menu to revive Noct, not realizing that the menu eventually times out if you don't do anything.  So I think you either need to 1) have no way of reviving Noct or otherwise ending the fight, or 2) take no action to revive Noct for some time.

Comment: Ive gotten game over in the Final bonus dungeon, where you cant use items. If Noctis' HP falls to zero there, its game over, regardless of the state of your other team mates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, I believe that it's pretty difficult to get a Game Over screen during combat, unless you are just out of Phoenix Downs. There were only one or two times during my playthrough of FFXV where I ever thought I was going to get a Game Over (thanks to Galvanades here, as well), but I didn't. Noctis was allowed to use a Phoenix Down on himself with no HP and a depleted maximum HP bar. I believe that unless you fail to use a Phoenix Down within a specific timeframe after losing all maximum health, you will not get a Game Over screen.

According to the [wiki page on status conditions](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Final_Fantasy_XV_statuses), you only have a few seconds to do this:

> If a party member's max HP falls to 0 they are Down. If Noctis gets Downed it spells a Game Over unless he is revived within a few seconds. Downed party members can be saved with Phoenix Downs.

Additionally, if you are playing on Easy mode, it's even *harder* to get a Game Over screen during combat, as [Carbuncle](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Carbuncle_(Final_Fantasy_XV)) will show up once per combat to prevent what would otherwise be a Game Over.

> In Easy Mode Carbuncle appears when the player enters critical condition to heal Noctis, and can appear in both dungeons and the open world. He can appear once per battle. He can also randomly appear in the background of photos taken by Prompto.

---

However, there are a few other ways to get Game Over screens.

From experience, the most common way (after beating the game) to get a Game Over is to [fail to land the Regalia Type-F properly](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/297534/how-do-i-land-my-plane-without-crashing), as failing to land gracefully [*almost*](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/298450/162442) always ends in a Game Over screen.

Another way, mentioned [here](http://www.gosunoob.com/final-fantasy-xv/ffxv-errors-problems/) is to fail to follow Ardyn closely enough when he is leading you in his car.

> There’s a part in Final Fantasy XV where you have to follow Ardyn in your car, the Regalia. It’s meant to be a simple part of the game, and if you somehow fall behind, Ardin will slow down, so there’s no way you can lose him. However, some players have experienced a glitch in which Ardin will just shoot off at full speed and they lose him and get a Game Over. Unfortunately, there’s no known solution to this bug yet. Hopefully, it will be fixed in the future.

I didn't personally encounter this, but it sounds pretty funny, aside from the whole making you hit a Game Over, and all.

Comment: I assume another way to get Game Over is to fail to complete a timed objective in the allotted time, though I've never actually tested this.

Comment: Yeah, you can get game over on a bunch of story missions. I did once when you have to destroy the airships attacking the train you're on. Being on one when they blow up is not a good idea. :p Obviously I was asking about battles though, and wasn't looking for an exhaustive list. Although between the bit about Ardyn waiting for you (usually) and being able to use a phoenix down when you run out of hp, I'm starting to wonder how many of those warnings were bluffs. Yet it's so easy to crash the Regalia Type-F. Go figure.